# What does this equation mean? Shouldn't the solution be a 1x3 matrix instead of a value?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

If we have a function

[image]

then what is

[image]

equal to?

The solutions are all single values, but if D(1,2,3) is the jacobian matrix on the point (1,2,3) and f(3,2,1) the function on that point, it should give a 1x3 matrix?

Comment: Might it be a directional derivative? That is, the derivative in the direction $(1, 2, 3)$, from the point $(3, 2, 1)$?

Comment: This could also mean$$\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial z\partial y\partial x}(3,2,1)$$

Comment: oh, you may be right, I'll check

Comment: Maybe

Directional derivative of f at the point (3,2,1) and in the direction of the vector (1,2,3)